# Is it bad practice to modify view after viewDidDisappear called?

Tags: ios, memory-management, timer, uikit

I have `UITabBarController` and in one of the `UIViewController` there I scroll `UICollectionView` each 5 second using `Timer`. Here is short code how I do it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureTimer()
}

private func configureTimer() {
    slideTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(scrollCollectionView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func scrollCollectionView() {
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: someIndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

It perfectly works. But I think it has a big issue. Of course, I can open another screen from this `UIViewController` (for example, I can tap to another tab or push another `UIViewController`). It means, my `UIViewController`'s view, containing `UICollectionView`, disappears. In another words, `viewDidDissapear` will be called. But my timer still exists and I am having strong reference to it, possibly, there is retain cycle. It keeps working and each 5 second `scrollCollectionView` method is called even my view dissapeared. I don't know how, but iOS somehow handles it. In other words, it can modify view even it is not visible. How is that possible and is it good practice? Of course, I can invalidate my timer in `viewDidDissapear` and start it in `viewDidAppear`. But I don't want to loose my timer value and don't want to start it from zero again. Or may be it is ok to invalidate my timer in `deinit`? 
My question covers pretty common situation. For instance, if I make network request and open another `UIViewController`. After that request finished, I should modify UI, but now am on another screen. Is it ok to allow iOS to modify UI even it is not visible?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. If the timer is updating the UI at some interval, you definitely should start it in `viewDidAppear` and stop it in `viewDidDisappear`. There’s no point in wasting resources updating a view that is not visible.
2. By doing this, you can solve your strong reference cycle, too.
3. In terms of “losing” your timer value and starting at zero, we generally would just save the time you’re counting from or to and calculate the necessary value when restarting the timer later.

   We do this, anyway, because you really shouldn’t be using timers to increment values because you’re technically not assured that they’ll be called with the frequency you expect.

   All of that said, I don’t know what timer “value” you’re worried about losing in this example.

But definitely don’t waste time updating a UI that is no longer visible. It’s not scalable and blurs the distinction between the model (what you’re counting to or from) from the UI (the update that happens every five seconds).

Comment: Ok, you wrote that `There’s no point in wasting resources updating a view that is not visible.` I accept this point, but let me write some example: I have 5 screens in my tab bar and in one of them I make network request and immediately tap on another tab. Previous screen's view is not visible anymore, but after finishing network request, iOS is able to modify UI if needed. Is it ok to allow iOS to behave like that?

Comment: Sure, in that particular example. I might let the request finish and update the UI. But I’d also make sure to use `weak` references so that the network request doesn’t keep strong reference to the view controller, but rather, ensure it’s only the the tab bar controller that’s doing that. But repeating timers, display links, very complicated animations, and the like, no, I’d cancel them as a general guideline.